# How to append "optional" text to form input label

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I'm new to Angular 2 and trying to append a text to form inputs that are optionals.

Something like this (`app-optional`):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label app-optional>
    Name
    ... input here ...
  </label>
</div>
```

Which should result in:

Name *- optional*

How could I achieve this? Or could you suggest a better way?

Comment: Do you want the string you type in input tag to be displayed after Name?

Comment: No I want the `app-optional` to append the text " - optional" after the label (Name). So the resulting label would be "Name - optional"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    Name - <app-optional></app-optional>
  </label>
</div>
```

In **html** of app-optional component:

```
Optional
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to solve it with `<ng-content>` like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label app-optional>
    Name
    ... input here ...
  </label>
</div>
```

**optional.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Translations } from '../../translations/translations';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-optional]',
  templateUrl: './optional.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./optional.component.scss']
})
export class OptionalComponent {
  constructor(public T: Translations) {}
}
```

**optional.component.html**

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<span class="optional"><em> - {{T.OPTIONAL}}</em></span>
```

**optional.component.scss**

```
.optional {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```